# draw a graph with mouse using qcustom plot

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I'm trying to use qt library qcustomplot to draw a graph which was taken from a user by mouse.

I have tried something like this:

```
void MainWindow::makePlot()
{
    ui->customPlot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag | QCP::iRangeZoom | QCP::iSelectAxes |
                                QCP::iSelectLegend | QCP::iSelectPlottables);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(-8, 8);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(-5, 5);
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();

    ui->customPlot->plotLayout()->insertRow(0);
    QCPTextElement *title = new QCPTextElement(ui->customPlot, "Interaction Example", QFont("sans", 17, QFont::Bold));
    ui->customPlot->plotLayout()->addElement(0, 0, title);

    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");
    ui->customPlot->legend->setVisible(true);
    QFont legendFont = font();
    legendFont.setPointSize(10);
    ui->customPlot->legend->setFont(legendFont);
    ui->customPlot->legend->setSelectedFont(legendFont);
    ui->customPlot->legend->setSelectableParts(QCPLegend::spItems); // legend box shall not be selectable, only legend items

    ui->customPlot->rescaleAxes();

    // connect slot that ties some axis selections together (especially opposite axes):
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(selectionChangedByUser()), this, SLOT(selectionChanged()));
    // connect slots that takes care that when an axis is selected, only that direction can be dragged and zoomed:
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(mousePress()));
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(mouseWheel(QWheelEvent*)), this, SLOT(mouseWheel()));

    // make bottom and left axes transfer their ranges to top and right axes:
    connect(ui->customPlot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
    connect(ui->customPlot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->yAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));

    // connect some interaction slots:
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(axisDoubleClick(QCPAxis*,QCPAxis::SelectablePart,QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(axisLabelDoubleClick(QCPAxis*,QCPAxis::SelectablePart)));
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(legendDoubleClick(QCPLegend*,QCPAbstractLegendItem*,QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(legendDoubleClick(QCPLegend*,QCPAbstractLegendItem*)));
    connect(title, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(titleDoubleClick(QMouseEvent*)));

    // connect slot that shows a message in the status bar when a graph is clicked:
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(plottableClick(QCPAbstractPlottable*,int,QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(graphClicked(QCPAbstractPlottable*,int)));

    // setup policy and connect slot for context menu popup:
    ui->customPlot->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(ui->customPlot, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(contextMenuRequest(QPoint)));


}
```

Is it possible with this library, and how can I to do it?
I would appreciate it if you can show me any example.

Comment: your question is ambiguous, what is the problem you have? Do you want to draw the points, or join the points?

Comment: actually i want to draw mouse trace on the plot
like painting a graph

Comment: Explain yourself better, besides explaining what your code does, I see you make connections. What is it for? Is that code workable or have you just copied it from some example? It would be great to indicate with an image what you want to obtain.

Comment: this is only an example of qcustomplot interaction
i did'nt change it 
i like to add a slot to it to draw/make  gragh with user's mouse track

Comment: What would be the interaction with the mouse? in the example that you want to use as a base, if I press the mouse, the whole graph moves, so that it is impossible to draw with the mouse. When do you want me to start painting the graph and when do you want it to end? please be more detailed in your description.

Comment: your right that feature can be cancelled simply

Comment: i'm trying to find a solution to get the mouse click position and track it and save it to a list or array ir anythin after that i can plot it

Comment: To get mouse click position you use:
`void QCustomPlot::mousePress ( QMouseEvent *  event)`
`double QCPAxis::pixelToCoord ( double  value) const`